# is function call on gtm usable to send events to Clevertap?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Currently using the GTM Legacy SDK on my Android App, and the new Firebase + GTM SDK seems to be able to support config of events to send to others like Appsflyer and Kochava. Can the GTM legacy SDK do that too?

Comment: Are you asking if the new Firebase + GTM SDK can send events to CleverTap? Or do you want to know if the GTM Legacy SDK can send events to CleverTap? CleverTap is not affiliated to GTM as a vendor yet so currently, you can create custom tags as mentioned here - https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/advanced-config#add-custom-tags-and-variables For legacy versions also you can set up custom function calls to send data to CleverTap using the CleverTap SDK

Comment: thanks. reckon the SDK will have to be implemented separately in the app? or can it be initialized via the GTM app sdk as well?